# ANDROID Remove reminder

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

I have reminder with a known ID, but couldn't find a solution to delete it... I have added Notification this way: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html and with AlarmManager...

I believe that solution should be something like:

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(ShowEmission.this, CustomAlarm.class);
intentAlarm.putExtra...
...
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, .., intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
am.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

But have some thoughts about it ... since the command to set is:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, requestCode, intent, flags)
```

so basically I have requestCode stored... Than I believe I should be able to delete the alarm with this requestCode...

Please advise me on this problem... I really have no idea how to solve it... Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to cancel this repeating alarm?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330522/how-to-cancel-this-repeating-alarm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Alarm Manager's `cancel` function.

Here's more [Help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330522/how-to-cancel-this-repeating-alarm)