# How to Stop Repeating Alarm Services in Android?

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager, repeat

I have totalTime = 1 hr and and intervalTime = 5min, both are in millisecond,

I want to repeat my  GPSSetting services every interval and after completion of totaltime  this repeating shoud be stop.

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(C2DMReceiver.this, GPSSetting.class);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
                        C2DMReceiver.this, 0, intent1, 0);
                am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis(), intervalTime,
                        pendingIntent);
```

So how to i can stop this repeating alarm ?

Regards,
Girish

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330522/how-to-cancel-this-repeating-alarm

Answer (score 6):

Create the same `PendingIntent` as when you registered the alarm and use `AlaramManager.cancel()` to cancel it.

Comment: Store the first time the alarm runs somewhere and calculate the elapsed time each time it runs. If it is more than 1 hour, cancel the alarm.

Comment: No, but here's a hint: you can get the current time using `System.currentTimeMillis()`. One hour is `60 * 60 * 1000` milliseconds. Do the math.

Comment: how to calculate  elapsed time ?

Comment: Last hint: `elapsed = t2 - t1`

Comment: I want to be Automaticaly Cancel Alarm after 1 hr..then how i can do this ?

Comment: can you help here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23316413/alarm-not-getting-stopped/23320549?noredirect=1#23320549

Comment: can you please help me to solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51542099/cant-stop-the-ringing-alarm-from-another-activity#51542099 @NikolayElenkov

Answer (score 4):

If you have set alarm service for repeating interval of time and you want to cancel your services, then this solution will help you, here first of all i am creating repeating services after every 30 sec, but when i'll press the stop button then it will cancel all the services which i have generated.

```
  public void AlarmService_afte30sec()
   {

       Toast.makeText(this, "Starting  Alarm Services", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, StartAlarmServices.class);
       pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, myIntent, 0);

               alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                int sec=30;
                alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), sec*1000, pendingIntent);
     }
```

Now i'll stop/cancel this services using the same "pendingintent" and "alarmManager", to cancel this the code will be

```
  public void stopservice()
 {
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);      
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass an intent extra value as 1 hours (or any) from current system time. Then you can check that value from inside the onBind() event of the service and compare it. Following is an example:

```
 //your code:
 AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(C2DMReceiver.this, GPSSetting.class);

 //my code:
 intent1.putExtra("end", System.currentTimeMillis() + 3600000); //current time plus 1 hour

 //your code:
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
                    C2DMReceiver.this, 0, intent1, 0); //You might wanna give PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT as flag.
            am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis(), intervalTime,
                    pendingIntent);
```

Then inside the onBind() methode:

```
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 long end = intent.getLongExtra("end", 0);
 if(end <= System.currentTimeMillis()){
      AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
      PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
                    this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
      am.cancel(pendingIntent);
 }
    return null;
}
```

Not sure if it will work for services but it worked for BroadcastReceiver.

Answer (score 0):

You can cancel the alarm by passing the the same pending intent you used while setting up in the cancel method of alarm manager:

```
am.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

Comment: @maneesh....I want to be Automaticaly Cancel Alarm after 1 hr..then how i can do this ?

Comment: you have to set another alarm which will act right after one hour and responsible for just only cancelling the specific alarm