# Alarm not getting stopped

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am trying to stop the alarm and checking it whether it stopped or not, but it always returns true means alarm is working. I tried to stop the alarm based on the answer in the link https://stackoverflow.com/a/17616299/1226882 but it doesnt work for me.

Please refer the below code

- **Start Alarm**

  ```
  public static void startSchedulerAlaram(Context ctx) {

  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
  calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
  calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0); 
  calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
  calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
  calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

  if (calendar.compareTo(Calendar.getInstance()) <= 0)
      calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

  AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) ctx
          .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

  Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, Alaram_Receiver.class);
  intent.setAction(Utility.SCHEDULE_ACTION);

  PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, 1, intent,0);
  alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
  calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);

  log("Scheduler Alarm", "Started");

  }
  ```
- **Stop Alarm**

  ```
  public static void stopSchedulerAlaram(Context ctx) {

  Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, Alaram_Receiver.class);
  intent.setAction(Utility.SCHEDULE_ACTION);
  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, 1,
          intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
  AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) ctx
          .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
  alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

  log("Scheduler Alarm", "Stopped");
  }
  ```
- **Check Alarm**

  ```
  public static boolean checkSchedulerAlaram(Context ctx) {

  boolean alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, 1, new Intent(ctx,Alaram_Receiver.class).setAction(Utility.SCHEDULE_ACTION),
          PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);

  return alarmUp;
  }
  ```

Comment: post the part where you use the stopSchedulerAlaram()

Comment: I am using `stopSchedulerAlaram()` from Activity like `if (Utility.checkSchedulerAlaram(this))
    Utility.stopSchedulerAlaram(this);`

Comment: I am calling start,stop and check from same activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass `different id for set alarm`

```
PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, id, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

For `cancel alarm you have pass same`id`that you used for set`.

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, id,
        intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) ctx
        .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Still not working, i tried to set different id for stopping alarm.

Comment: @droid_dev it should work if you are using same id for set and cancel alarm

Comment: it will work but checkSchedulerAlaram return  response after 1 min   or half minute

Comment: Does the extras have to be passed as well? I have been trying to cancel a repeating alarm. But it doesn't work. I pass the same action code, intent (without extra) and flag and still does not work

Answer (score 1):

You are using this code to determine if the alarm is set or not:

```
boolean alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, 1, new Intent(ctx,Alaram_Receiver.class).setAction(Utility.SCHEDULE_ACTION),
    PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
```

This code relies on the presence of the `PendingIntent` to determine if the alarm is scheduled or not.

When you cancel the alarm you do this:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, 1,
    intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) ctx
    .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

This cancels the alarm, but does not remove the `PendingIntent` from the system. Since you rely on the presence/absence of the `PendingIntent` to know if the alarm has been scheduled or not you also need to cancel the `PendingIntent` so that it will be removed from the system. Do that like this (after you cancel the alarm):

```
pendingIntent.cancel();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code that i am using to cancel the alarm service

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class);
         PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
         AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
         alarmManager.cancel(sender);
```