# Android: Unable to cancel repeating alarm

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am creating a repeating alarm. This works fine using the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this.ctx, AlarmReceiver.class);
intent.setAction("" + notificationId);
intent.putExtra(AlarmReceiver.TITLE, alarmTitle);
intent.putExtra(AlarmReceiver.SUBTITLE, alarmSubTitle);
intent.putExtra(AlarmReceiver.TICKER_TEXT, alarmTicker);
intent.putExtra(AlarmReceiver.NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationId);

 PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.ctx, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
 AlarmManager am = getAlarmManager();
 am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerTime, 60000, sender);
```

Now I want to cancel an existing notification message (which pops up every minute for testing purposes), I invoke the following code, passing it an identical notificationId:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this.ctx, AlarmReceiver.class);
intent.setAction("" + notificationId);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(this.ctx, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

     AlarmManager am = getAlarmManager();
     try {
          am.cancel(pi);

         } catch (Exception e) {
       Log.e(PLUGIN_NAME, "AlarmManager update was not canceled. " + e.toString());
}
```

I see that `pi != null`, however the notification keeps coming and is not being cancelled. Both code snippets reside in the same class.

Basically I have two questions:
 - How can I cancel a single alarm using its unique ID?
 - How can I cancel all alarms, regardless of the ID?

UPDATE: I found that posting my issue here helps to get my mind straight. Changing the cancel code from:

`PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getService( ... )`

To:

`PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( ... )`

Helps to solve question 1. However the code to cancel all events, still does not work:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this.ctx, AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.ctx, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

AlarmManager am = getAlarmManager();
am.cancel(pi);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to cancel this repeating alarm?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330522/how-to-cancel-this-repeating-alarm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a noob here. But I think if you want to cancel the alarm, you have to use the exact same instance of PendingIntent. That means "their action, data, type, class, and categories are the same" as defined by filterEquals(Intent) . Therefore, you need to use the same requestCode here, not 0. Maybe you could use a list to store the Notification Ids, and iterate them to cancel all alarms.

Comment: I am affraid you're right, it seems I have to keep track of all IDs and remove them one-by-one if I like to have cancelAll functionality. I guess I need to records these IDs anyway if I need to reregister them once the device reboots.

Comment: +1 Yeah, was just scratching my head over why the alarmmanager from last debug session still was going strong, turned out the parameters passed to PendingIntent.getBroadcast() in start had to be exact same ones in cancel.

Comment: In my app, if use FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT, the alarm cannot be canceled, if change to FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT, then the cancel will work. I don't know why. Can someone explain it ?

Answer (score 0):

I think , you should use same AlarmManager object to cancel the alram and also try to use same PendingIntent.