# AlarmManager not Canceling my setRepeating Alarm

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, android-alarms

I have an activity (setting alarm) that creates a repeating alarm, I need to cancel that alarm from another activity (cancel alarm). I am unable to cancel the alarm. What am I doing wrong?:

```
public class settingalarm...

am =(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent alrm = new Intent(context, z.class);
alrm.setAction(ALARM);
alrm.putExtra(x, x);
PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, alrm, 0);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 0, 30000, alarmIntent);
```

I have another activity that needs to cancel the existing alarm:

```
public class cancelingalarm...

am =(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent alrm = new Intent(context, z.class);
PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, alrm, 0);
am.cancel(alarmIntent);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try this link and apply for code,

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330522/how-to-cancel-this-repeating-alarm][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330522/how-to-cancel-this-repeating-alarm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an equivalent `Intent` for the `PendingIntent` you create. In this that means setting the same action. BTW, since you are using an explicit Intent (you specify the class name), there is really no need to add an action as well.

In short: either remove `alrm.setAction(ALARM);` or use it in both places.

Comment: thank you sir! makes sense, i needed to add `alrm.setAction(ALARM);` to the cancelingalarm activity.

Answer (score 0):

I am making intent Global & working for me:--

```
private Intent alrm;


alrm = new Intent(context, z.class);
```