# Starting and stopping a service using 3 alarms

Tags: android

I want my app to start at 9am everyday. for that I start Alarm_1 using `setRepeatingAlarm()` that starts at 9am everyday.

```
manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
    timeOn.getTimeInMillis(), 86400000,startingIntent);
```

From alarm_1, I start another alarm, MainAlarm, that repeatedly starts my service at the interval of 1min.

```
manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
    SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), duration, MainActivity.mainIntent);
```

I want my app to stop at 9pm everyday.

For that I start Alarm_2 using `setRepeatingAlarm()` that `cancel()` MainAlarm everyday at 9pm.

But this is not working as expected.

What should be done? Is there any problem because I am using 3 alarms?

The alarms do not work the next day.

```
     This is my cancel() code:
          public class AlarmReceiver2 extends BroadcastReceiver {
          @Override
          public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
         manager.cancel(MainActivity.mainIntent);
      MainActivity.mainIntent.cancel();
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I don't think there is a problem with having 3 alarms.

Secondly, perhaps you can add the code that you use to try and cancel with. A trick here is that you need your `PendingIntent` to be identical to the one you used to start the alarm - that's why it will be useful to see the cancel code.

---

Have a look at my answer here on a related question:

- [Stop a service at specific time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16479874/383414)

---

The question is similar enough that I don't feel I should copy the whole answer across, but here is a summary which links to a @commonsware answer:

---

Below answer copied from [How to cancel this repeating alarm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330522/how-to-cancel-this-repeating-alarm)

Call `cancel()` on AlarmManager with an equivalent PendingIntent to the one you used with `setRepeating()`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceive.class);
PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,
               0, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

alarmManager.cancel(sender);
```

Comment: am I not doing the same thing?

Comment: perhaps show us the cancel code - its hard to know if you are doing the same thing