# Where/How to set AlarmManager alarms to avoid duplicates

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I'm fairly new to Android, so please forgive my naiveté.

The app I am working on needs to wake up every hour and do some background data collection. I'm using `AlarmManager` to set a repeating alarm that starts the service.

I'm currently setting up the alarm in the `MainActivity` in the `onCreate` method. My concern is that if the app is closed and reopened and the `onCreate` method is called again, it would duplicate the alarms. Am I incorrect in assuming this?

One way I'm thinking about circumventing this to use a boolean in `SharedPreferences`. Is there a more standard way of approaching this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: I think the user should have the option to set the alarm versus the alarm automatically being created in the onCreate method. That way, the user can decide whether or not to set multiple alarms.

Answer (score 5):

You can set alarm once avoiding duplicates without any problem.

1. You can statically set broadcast receiver [once the OS finishes booting](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED). Register pending intent via [PendingIntent.getService()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getService(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int)) and configure the AlarmManager in the receiver's onReceive() method.
2. Please note also that every method PendingIntent.getBroadcast(), PendingIntent.getService(), PendingIntent.getActivity() or PendingIntent.getActivities() has `flags` parameter. You can request your PendingIntent with [PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_NO_CREATE) flag set. This means that if the system has identical PendingIntent registered then the null is returned. Otherwise new PendingIntent instance is created. Thus, you can rely on this flag to check if your alarm is already set.

Read more about PendingIntent in my response to the similar problem, please([Usage of PendingIntent.cancel() and AlarmManager.cancel()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29977332/usage-of-pendingintent-cancel-and-alarmmanager-cancel/30001552#30001552)).

Basically, you can still rely on setting your alarm in launching activity by checking first whether you have PendingIntent registered thanks to the [PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_NO_CREATE) set.

Hope you now understand how to do it.

Comment: On point 2, if my reading of the docs is correct then it sounds like you have it backwards. Null will be returned if the Intent _isn't_ already registered, not if it is.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_NO_CREATE

Answer (score 3):

In onCreate I would probably just cancel all alarms, then set a new alarm. Psuedo code would be something like

1. Create pending intent for your alarm
2. call `AlarmManager.cancel` with that pending intent http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#cancel%28android.app.PendingIntent%29
3. set your alarm with the same pending intent.

Comment: Ah. I see! Thank you. That makes sense. Do you think onCreate is the correct place to do something like this? Thanks again.

Comment: If you have an `Application` class that's a little better suited. Also, alarms are cleared on every reboot, so you'll need a `BroadcastReceiver` that listens for the boot completed broadcast so you can reset your alarms.

Comment: `if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(userId) && alarmManager == null) {

                alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainScreenActivity.this, AlarmReceive.class);
                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainScreenActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);
                alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
                alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), Constants.trackTimeInterval, pendingIntent); // every 60 minutes
            }` Is this right way?