# How to cancel a repeating alarm

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm, repeatingalarm

I have a repeating alarm at the top of every hour to check if a notification needs to be sent. I have on/off buttons for it but the off does not seem to cancel it. There are quite a few questions about canceling alarms on SO but **none of them were able to help**. Here is what I have.

**Main Activity**

```
public void onSendNotificationsButtonClick(View view) {
    NotificationEventReceiver.setupAlarm(getApplicationContext());
}

public void stopSendNotificationsButtonClick(View view) {
    NotificationEventReceiver.cancelAlarm(getApplicationContext());
}
```

**Event receiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver**

```
public static void setupAlarm(Context context) {
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = getStartPendingIntent(context);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            getTriggerAt(new Date()),
            NOTIFICATIONS_INTERVAL_IN_HOURS * AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR,
            alarmIntent);
}

public static void cancelAlarm(Context context) {
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = getDeleteIntent(context);
    alarmIntent.cancel();
    alarmManager.cancel(alarmIntent);
}

private static long getTriggerAt(Date now) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(now);
    calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, NOTIFICATIONS_INTERVAL_IN_HOURS); //change here to set notification interval
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    return calendar.getTimeInMillis();
}

private static PendingIntent getStartPendingIntent(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationEventReceiver.class);
    intent.setAction(ACTION_START_NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}

public static PendingIntent getDeleteIntent(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmManager.class);
    intent.setAction(ACTION_DELETE_NOTIFICATION);
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    Intent serviceIntent = null;
    if (ACTION_START_NOTIFICATION_SERVICE.equals(action)) {
        Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onReceive from alarm, starting notification service");
        serviceIntent = NotificationIntentService.createIntentStartNotificationService(context);
    } else if (ACTION_DELETE_NOTIFICATION.equals(action)) {
        Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onReceive delete notification action, starting notification service to handle delete");
        serviceIntent = NotificationIntentService.createIntentDeleteNotification(context);
    }

    if (serviceIntent != null) {
        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, serviceIntent);
    }
}
```

**edit:** Changed the function based on answers, still does not cancel the alarm.

```
public static void cancelAlarm(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationServiceStarterReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(sender);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to cancel this repeating alarm?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330522/how-to-cancel-this-repeating-alarm)

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
public static void cancelAlarm(Context context) {
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceive.class);
PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.cancel(sender);
}
```

This article: [How to cancel this repeating alarm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330522/how-to-cancel-this-repeating-alarm)

Comment: I have seen this article and that does not work, see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

set the unique request code to pending intent while setting the alarm and cancel it with same request code and cancel the pending intent too.

```
    public static void cancelAlarm(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceive.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, request_code, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(sender);
    sender.cancel(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Please try this

 public void cancelAlarmIfExists(Context mContext, int requestCode, Intent intent) {
    try {
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, requestCode, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.cancel(pendingIntent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```