# How to trigger the alarm multiple times on same day?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, android-alarms

For example, first alarm to be triggered at 10:00 am, second alarm to be triggered at 11:15 am and Third to be at 11.45 am.... Like this without any common difference between each instance I need to trigger alarm multiple times.

If I had common difference than repeat function can be used, but without common difference between times I need to trigger it. So, how can i trigger the alarm multiple times?

Comment: Set multiple alarms. You don't have to use a repeating alarm.

Comment: Its simple You can set multiple alarms or set individual alarms .

Comment: set the multiple alarms in same day

Answer (score 0):

```
You can set multiple alarm

Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, HOUR_1);
            calendar1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, MINUTES);
            calendar1.set(Calendar.SECOND, SEC);

            Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, HOUR_2);
            calendar2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, MINUTES);
            calendar2.set(Calendar.SECOND, SEC);

            Calendar calendar3 = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar3.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, HOUR_3);
            calendar3.set(Calendar.MINUTE, MINUTES);
            calendar3.set(Calendar.SECOND, SEC);

            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar1.getTimeInMillis(), ALARM_INTERVAL , pendingIntent1);//here interval is 24*60*60*1000
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar2.getTimeInMillis(), ALARM_INTERVAL , pendingIntent2);//24*60*60*1000
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar3.getTimeInMillis(), ALARM_INTERVAL , pendingIntent3);//24*60*60*1000

    }
```

Comment: how to set alarm  dynamically and cancel it ..?

Comment: follow this to cancel  alarm http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330522/how-to-cancel-this-repeating-alarm

Answer (score 0):

from this link "http://www.satyakomatineni.com/item/3503" , `ArrayList<Calendar>calenderList=new ArrayList<Calendar();
calender=Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault(),Locale.getDefault());`calender.set(Calendar.DATE,resultDay);
calender.set(Calendar.MONTH,8);
calender.set(Calendar.YEAR,2016);calender.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,14);calender.set(Calendar.MINUTE,30);calender.set(Calendar.SECOND,10);

```
for(int n=0;n<calenderList.size();n++)      
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(

Intent intent = new Intent(TvActivity.this,TVAlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                this.getApplicationContext(),n, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);          AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);         alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calenderList.get(n).getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```