# How to add 3 Dates to AlarmManager in android

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have 3 different `Date` objects and I want to pass them to `AlarmManager` object to alert me when they occur.

May I need to use

```
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
         cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 2);
```

to add `2` minutes to the calender, but how to add a future  date object to the calender ?

Do I need A `Calender` object, or I need a separate `Calender` object for each  Date ?
Them for `AralamManger` do I need one object to 3 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will advice you to use three different Calendar objects in which future dates will be set as below:

```
Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
            Date future_date=new Date();
             future_date.setHours(hour);
                future_date.setMinutes(min);
                future_date.set(year, month, day);
                calendar1.setTime(future_date);

....OR.......
calendar1.set(year, month, day, hourOfDay, minute)
   ----------------
```

Look like u want to setup multiple alarm...below is link for answer
[How can I setup multiple alarms in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273342/how-can-i-setup-multiple-alarms-in-android)

Comment: and using one AlarmManager object ?

Comment: am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
calendar1.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent); -----OR -----am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
future_date.getTime(), pendingIntent); Please set it as Answer if it is useful to you

Comment: ok I will accept the answer , but I can set more than one calnder for the same AlarmManager , right ?

Comment: U can set multiple alarm with same AlarmManager instance by passing different requestcode....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273342/how-can-i-setup-multiple-alarms-in-android

Comment: by setting up pending intent...PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Context context, int requestCode, Intent intent, int flags)